# An issue with template method's instance and std::vector.begin() as argument

Tags: c++, templates, vector, iterator

I want to make an overloaded class `operator()` method that can take any kind of iterators (including pointers) as an arguments. I try to make this using templates:

```
class SimpleFunction
{
public:
    virtual double operator()(double x) = 0;
    template<class Iterator> void operator()(Iterator x, Iterator y, unsigned int n);
    void operator()(const vector<double> &x, const vector<double> &y);
};

template<class Iterator> void SimpleFunction::operator()(Iterator x, Iterator y, unsigned int n)
{
    while (x != x + n)
        *y++ = operator()(*x++);
}

void SimpleFunction::operator()(const vector<double> &x, const vector<double> &y)
{
    operator()(x.begin(), y.begin(), x.size());
}
```

But when i try to compile my code, i get an error:

`D:\MyFiles\functions\simple.cpp:9: error: C3892: 'y' : you cannot assign to a variable that is const`

I cannot understand why i get this error, because `std::vector` must have `begin()` method, that returns non-const iterator.
How can i avoid this error?

Comment: your both containers are const. it means begin() and end() return const_interator

Comment: [OT]: note that all iterators don't have `x + n` defined ([RandomAccessIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator) has this requirement, but not [InputIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/InputIterator)). [std::istream_iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) is an example of InputIterator which is not RandomIterator.

Comment: Thanks for coments! One more thing i have figured out is that the template method must be defined in а header file (in my actual source code it was in a .cpp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::vector` has const-overloaded `begin` and `end` member functions. Because of this, in the template call `operator()(x.begin(), y.begin(), x.size());`, the `Iterator` is deduced to be `vector<double>::const_iterator`. If you mean to modify the passed-in vector `y`, don't have it be a `const vector<double>&`:

```
void SimpleFunction::operator()(const vector<double> &x, vector<double> &y)
```

Note that you will need to use two template type arguments instead of one, if you insist on `x` and `y` having different types:

```
template<class Iterator, class IteratorY> void SimpleFunction::operator()(IteratorX x, IteratorY y, unsigned int n)
```